# Most efficient way to Normalized an existing dataset in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, normalize

I have a flat dataset that I would like to normalize. The Dataset is existing and the source is not changeable so defining a better data structure is not an option. I have managed to "normalize" and restructure the data but I am not sure how efficient it would be when the number of rows starts to grow? Here is what I have, like I said it works just looking for a more elegant solution...

Here is what the ideal output would look like

```
    {ArticleID: "ABC123", 
Status: "Scheduled", 
Articles: { 
  ArticleID: "ABC123", 
  Region: US, 
  PubTypeID: "EO", 
  PubType: "Europe Order", 
  Created: "01/01/2013", 
  Scheduled: "03/02/2013"
  },{ 
  ArticleID: "ABC234", 
  Region: US, 
  PubTypeID: "EO", 
  PubType: "Europe Order", 
  Created: "01/01/2013", 
  Scheduled: "03/02/2013"
  }
}
```

[Here is a link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremywrags/TLENN/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var data = new Array( 
{ 
  ArticleID: "ABC123", 
  Region: 'US', 
  PubTypeID: "EO", 
  PubType: "Europe Order", 
  Created: "01/01/2013", 
  Scheduled: "03/02/2013"
},
{ 
  ArticleID: "ABC123", 
  Region: 'RU', 
  PubTypeID: "EO", 
  PubType: "Europe Order", 
  Created: "01/01/2013", 
  Scheduled: "04/02/2013"
},
{ 
  ArticleID: "ABC763", 
  Region: 'EO', 
  PubTypeID: "EO", 
  PubType: "Europe Order", 
  Created: "01/01/2013", 
  Scheduled: "03/02/2013"
},
{ 
  ArticleID: "ABC498", 
  Region: 'JP', 
  PubTypeID: "EN", 
  PubType: "Europe Order", 
  Created: "01/01/2013", 
  Scheduled: "03/02/2013"
}
);

var Articles = new Array(); 
var pID = "";
var cID = "";

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
cID = item.ArticleID;
var entries = new Array();
if(cID != pID)
{
    $.each(data, function(j, item2) {
        var entry = new Object();
        if(cID === item2.ArticleID)
        {
            entry.ArticlID = item2.ArticleID;
            entry.Region = item2.Region;
            entry.PubTypeID = item2.PubTypeID
            entries.push(entry);
        }
    });
    Articles.push({ArtilceID: cID, Entries: entries})
    pID = cID
}
});

alert(Articles.length);
alert(Articles[0].Entries.length);


});
```

Comment: can't help until you tell us exactly how you need to access/process this data. one person's elegant "zomg this is perfect" is another person's "what a load of crap"

Comment: @MarcB in this case we're talking about an O(n^2) solution, so I think it's fair to say that the OP can definitely do much better, particularly for large datasets.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is O(n^2) and OP?

Answer (score 0):

One iteration should be enough. You can use a `groupBy` operation which utilizes a lookup object:

```
var byId = {};
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    if (data[i].ArticleID in byId)
        byId[data[i].ArticleID].push(data[i]);
    else
        byId[data[i].ArticleID] = [data[i]];
```

I don't know what you need exactly, but you could for example get the structure your original code build easily now by this:

```
var Articles = [];
for (var id in byId)
     Articles.push({
        ArtilceID: id,
        Entries: $.map(byId[id], function(item) {
            return {
                ArticlID: item.ArticleID,
                Region: item.Region,
                PubTypeID: item.PubTypeID
            };
        }) // not sure why you need to clone them, though
     });
```

Comment: My Goal is to create a Dashboard with Collapsable regions. I want to show a region head that has the Unique ArticleID's and then under each of those the associated articles. The way my data

Comment: ...and so you need your data grouped by article id. That's the six lines of code at the top, forget about the rest. Just enumerate the object with a for-in-loop